Electrophilic substitution of activated aromatic ring using dihydronaphtalene and NBS

I found this reaction on Wikipedia. Could anyone confirm and provide mechanism for it?
I don't understand how NBS can add bromine to a non allylic position.

It's somewhat interesting example, but wording of q. was very bad, and you still should elaborate.

The issue you mention is rather trivial, though. NBS is a source or Br2. You'd think Br2 has trouble with addition to double bonds?

People concentrate too much on Wohl–Ziegler bromination in which NBS still turns out to be a source or Br2.

NBS can be used as a source of Br+ for "bromonium ion" formation as described here
The "bromonium ion" then reacts with the highly electron-rich aromatic acting as a nucleophile to give the product drawn. It reacts at the benzylic site as the benzene ring stabilises +ve charge there.

But here Br is not attached to benzylic position, is it? Originally, it was a question and we needed to predict the product.

Br is not at the benzylic position. One tautomer of the bromium ion has positive charge at the benzylic position and Br at the phenethyl position - this is a favoured tautomer because of the stabilisation of the +ve charge and this drives where the electron-rich aromatic attacks.

@Waylander: I agree with the formation of the bromonium ion intermediate and the role of the methylated cathecol. But is free bromine formed in this case as opposed to the Wohl-Ziegler conditions at elevated temperature? This reaction is run at 0 deg. and in the presence of molecular sieves and a catalyst. One might entertain the idea that Sm(OTf)3 complexes with NBS on oxygen activating the bromine of NBS to nucleophilic attack by the double bond.

@user55119  That seems quite possible. The Sm(OTf)3 has to be doing something.
